# What is the expiration on Morton salt substitute?

Tags: food-safety, salt, seasoning

From what I read it says online the use by date is 5 years. It is composed of potassium chloride, fumeric acid, tricalcium phosphate and monocalcium phosphate.

I don't understand how these chemicals expire. Bacterial growth?, chemical reaction? If there is no chemical reaction how can these four chemicals become less potent or effective? Even if they absorb moisture so what, same thing happens when you swallow it.

Yet another mystery.

Comment: Location may matter. There may be a law that says every food has to have a *to consume by* date. This may be valid for salt, too, though there's nothing that can spoil.

Comment: ... I don't understand what your question is?  You have the expiration date.

Comment: @Bernhard Dobler. That would explain it. The bottle didn't have an expiration, that was google so it is probably so old that it was before the law passed. :- ) antique salt substitute.